# Как настроить маршрутизацию в express.js 4.+.+?

Tags: node.js, express

Целый день гуглю и не могу разобраться, как сделать маршрутизацию в express.js 4.+.+
Если у кого-то есть успешный опыт, то поделитесь, как сделать чтобы были маршруты `/`,  `get: '/users/:name'`, `post: '/users/:name'`
Все что я смог нагуглить, это вынести роутер в фасад и впервую очередь подключать его в `app.use(Facade.DEFAULT_ROUTER)` и потом его передавать для построения маршрутизации, но это не работает...

Answer (score 2):

А разве `app.get("/users/:name", function(req, res){})`  и аналогичный `app.post` больше не работают?

Посмотрите также на `app.route()` и `express.Router` для создания цепочки маршрутов.